# Let $f,g :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $g(x) = f(x) + (f(x))^5$. If $g \in C^k$ then $f \in C^k$.

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

Someone can help me on this question ? 
Section on the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Show that $x\mapsto x+x^5$ as a smooth inverse.

Comment: Don't get it... How can I do that and how this finish the problem ?

Comment: You can do that using the implicit function theorem and if $h$ is the smooth inverse, then $f(x)=h(g(x))$ shows the claim.

Comment: Is this right? Differentiate we get: $1+5x^4$ always greater than zero. So exists h such that $h(x+x^5)=x$ Then, $f(x)=h(g(x))$, I know $g,h \in C^k$ so i can conclude $f\in C^k$

Comment: How can I give a "useful comment" to your answer ?